# compare an element of a list with the following in a recursively way

Tags: java, list, cons

**Hi**,
Update: Thanks for all your suggestion

assuming that, this exercise it's like a rebus,
I have a list of numbers made with the concept of Cons and Nil,

```
List l = new Cons(**3**, new Cons(**2**,new Cons(**1**, new
Cons(**4**, new Cons(**1**, new Nil())))));
```

and I want to count how many of them are immediately followed by a lower number, recursively.

For example

```
[5,0,5,3].count() == 2, [5,5,0].count() == 1
```

The `count()` method is made by me **(it cannot have any parameters)**, the rest is default, and I can't make and other method or use already defined one's like add(),size()...
The **"NEXT" must have the next value after the current elem** but I can't get a solution.

Any solutions are welcome.

````
abstract class List {

    public abstract boolean empty();

    public abstract int first();

    public abstract int count();

}

class Cons extends List {

    private int elem;

    private List next;

  public Cons(int elem, List next) {

   this.elem = elem;

   this.next = next;

}

public boolean empty(){
 return false; 
}

public int first(){
 return elem;
}

@Override
public int count() {
  if(elem>NEXT) {
      return 1 + next.count();  
  }else {
      return next.count();      
 }

}

```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWo0v.jpg)
````

Comment: Why exactly can't you use `List` methods like `add()` and `size()`?

Comment: Because List is a type that is  created for this exercise and not the existing one. Furthermore the text of the exercise says that you can't add additional methods

Comment: Alright I understand, you can take a look at my answer and see if that meets your requirements. About the method creation restriction, are you not allowed to create new abstract methods or any methods in general? If the latter is the case then I will need to rethink my approach.

Comment: The  text of the exercise says: è vietato usare cast o definire altri metodi oltre a quelli presenti. L'invocazione del metodo count non deve modificare in alcun modo la lista L, that translated from Italian means: its forbidden to use cast or define other methods besides the existing ones. The invocation of the method count should not modify in any way the list L.

Comment: There is the full exercise https://imgur.com/a/SKBv2RT

Comment: I am guessing that including new constructors would also be considered a violation of exercise constraints. I will see what I can do to make it not implement any methods or constructors other then the one that is already declared.

Comment: That's an university test, so don't broke too much your head on it :P

Comment: Yea no worries, it's kinda dumb that you are not allowed to do your own implementation, you're only allowed to do it exactly the way the uni intended it to be done. This is not a good lesson for a future programmer, as you're often encourage to work outside the box and figure out unique ways of doing things to improve performance, stability and in general implement your own ideas.

Comment: Are you at least allowed to declare fields inside the existing classes? Also are you allowed to create your own classes? This would make things a lot easier.

Comment: I honestly don't think this is even possible with the limitations imposed on you. My current thought is to use reflection but that would involve external libraries, which I again assume you are not allow to use :D

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide the actual answer you were looking for which is a solution to the exercise you linked above. It should work within the constraints imposed on you, give it a go and tell me if it doesn't work in some way.

Comment: You are a genius!Thank you so much, your solution does exactly what it's supposed to do in the right way. I never thought about the fact that I should use the try and catch constructor, furthermore the way you compares the elem with the following it is simple but not so obvious. And about the fact that you said that is not a good lesson to use just what the uni, wants you to use..; it's so right that I swear I'll say it to the professor. Sorry but I can't upvote  you (my reputation is too low) thanks again

Comment: You could accept the answer though, it will mark the question as being truly answered and help others who are looking for similar implementations by telling them that the answer **works**. Also it would save the moderators the trouble of cleaning up the question later due to it being inactive, unanswered and pretty much dead. Read here for more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/541613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will create a recursive list with **N** elements with **N** value being defined by the size of the amount of elements found in the `int` array called `elements` in `RecursiveList` class. Call the `startRecursion()` method to create a recursive list with the defined elements and call `count()` to get the amount of elements in the array that are *immediately followed by a lower number*.

**Main Class**

*This your application entry point:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = RecursiveList.startRecursion().count();
    System.out.printf("List has %d recursive elements", count);
}
```

**RecursiveList Class**

```
abstract class RecursiveList {

    protected static int index = -1;
    protected static int[] elements = new int[]{ 5,2,1,4,3,2,6 };

    public static RecursiveList startRecursion() {
        return new Cons();
    }

    public abstract boolean empty();

    public abstract int count();

    public abstract Integer getElement();

    public static int incIndex() {
        return index += 1;
    }
}
```

**Cons Class**

```
public class Cons extends RecursiveList {

    private static int result;

    private final Integer elem;
    private final RecursiveList prev;
    private final RecursiveList next;

    private Cons(Cons parent) {

        prev = parent;
        elem = incIndex() < elements.length ? elements[index] : null;
        System.out.printf("Creating new Cons with element %d(%d)%n", elem, index);
        next = elem != null ? new Cons(this) : null;
    }

    Cons() {
        this(null);
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public /*@Nullable*/ Integer getElement() {
        return elem;
    }

    @Override
    public int count() {

        if (elem != null)
        {
            if (prev != null && elem < prev.getElement())
                result += 1;

            if (next != null) {
                return next.count();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alright here is the answer you were actually looking for. This completely conforms to the limitations imposed on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coLR9.jpg) exercise that you provided. The solution uses pure Java, neither the class nor any of it's method or field declarations were modified in any way and no such new elements were added. I've only added the implementation where the exercise said you should.

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List l = new Cons(3, new Cons(2,new Cons(1, new
            Cons(4, new Cons(1, new Nil())))));

    assert l.count() == 3;

    l = new Cons(5, new Nil());
    assert l.count() == 0;

    l = new Cons(5, new Cons(5, new Cons(0, new Nil())));
    assert l.count() == 1;

    l = new Cons(5, new Cons(0, new Cons(5, new Cons(3, new Nil()))));
    assert l.count() == 2;

    System.out.println("All tests completed successfully!");
}
```

**Cons Class**

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Cons extends List {
    private int elem;
    private List next;

    public Cons(int elem, List next) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public boolean empty()
    { return false; }

    public int first()
    { return elem; }

    public int count()
    {
        try {
            if (first() > next.first()) {
                return 1 + next.count();
            }
            else return next.count();
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Nil Class**

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Nil extends List {
    public boolean empty()
    { return true; }

    public int first()
    { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }

    public int count()
    {
        throw new IllegalAccessError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int NEXT(){
 if(next!=null)
   return next.first()
 else 
   throw new Exception("No next element")
}
```